# Merge cells in align environment

Tags: equations, align, columns

My goal is to produce something like that:

[image]

However, when I use the `align` environment I can't find how to merge columns, so the result is very ugly:

[image]

MWE:

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\begin{align}
  A&=B & C&=D & E&=F\\
  AA&=B & CC&=D & EE&=F\\
  % This lines break the alignment. I'd like it to be aligned with
  % the first columns, without shifting the other columns
  AA&=BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `\mathrlap` from `mathtools`:

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]
\begin{align}
  A&=B & C&=D & E&=F\\
  AA&=B & CC&=D & EE&=F\\
  AA&=\mathrlap{BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB}
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

[image]